# Переадресация запроса с nginx на apache2

Tags: nginx, proxy

Всем привет. Есть VPS (ubuntu), на нем стоит nginx. Мне нужно все запросы, которые идут на маршрут /telegram-bot/*, переадресовывать на прокси http://127.0.0.1:8085/

Попробовал это сделать таким образом:

```
server {
    server_name site.com;
    location / { deny: all; }
    add_header Allow "GET, POST" always;
    if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|POST)$ ) { return 405; }
    location ^~ /telegram-bot/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8085;
    }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Но переадресация не работает. Почему?

**UPD**: В логах /var/log/nginx/error.log:

> 2019/03/25 22:11:05 [error] 9550#9550: *1 access forbidden by rule,
>   client: *ip*, server: site.com, request: "GET /telegram-bot HTTP/1.1",
>   host: "site.com"

Comment: Как вы определяете, что переадресация не работает? Логи? Тексты ошибок?

Comment: @andreymal добавил в вопрос

Comment: Наверно, начать стоит с того, что `deny: all` это синтаксическая ошибка и у вас nginx вообще не должен был запуститься. То, что он у вас работает, означает, что вы что-то не договариваете: или вы показали нам не тот конфиг, или вы не перезапускали nginx после редактирования конфига